# Angular change Socket.io url on runtime

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io

I have my `app.module.ts` like this:

```
// Imports
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from './../../node_modules/ngx-socket-io';
const config: SocketIoConfig = {
  url: 'http://192.168.0.101:3000',
  options: {}
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    // modules..
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
  ],
  //..
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Would like to be able to change the `config.url` value. But i've no clue how to do it since changing the `config.url` value doesn't change it on `SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)` after initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to disconnect using

```
this.socket.disconnect()
```

and then create a new instance with

```
this.socket = io("http://foo")
```

The library is just a wrapper to socketio-client

Answer (score 2):

Just like @03c7c0ace395d80182db07ae2c30f0 said.

Solution:
The config in `app.module.ts` be like

```
let config: SocketIoConfig = {
  url: 'http://192.168.43.142:9780',
  options: {},
};
```

and made a service to handle the URL change (in this code only port change but should be same):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket, SocketIoConfig } from './../../../node_modules/ngx-socket-io';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SocketService {
  config: SocketIoConfig = {
    url: 'http://192.168.43.142:9780',
    options: {},
  };

  constructor(private socket: Socket) {
    this.socket = new Socket(this.config);
  }

  changeToAdminSocket() {
    this.socket.disconnect();
    this.config.url = 'http://192.168.43.142:9781'; // Note the port change
    this.socket = new Socket(this.config);
  }
}
```

Comment: For anybody trying this approach, just remember to disable the _autoConnect_ when importing the library into your module to avoid it creating a default socket: `SocketIoModule.forRoot({url:'',options:{autoConnect:false}})`